# How can I get Active Directory Password Policy Error in Java Client while changing password

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I am changing active directory password from java client. I am getting general error like 'Will Not Perform'. I am using windows 2003 server for active directory. How can I get specific errors like password strength or length error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 2003 along with the LDAP error code for "Will Not Perform", the AD returns an error message. That error message contains all the data you need. Part of it is [System Error Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which specifies more exact error, and sometimes the string ends with `data XXX`, which provides some more information, however I was never able to find from where XXX codes are taken (in most cases it is just 0), so you may need to experiment a little.

In your case the message will look similar to this one:

```
LDAP error 0x35. Unwilling To Perform (0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A0FC0, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0).
```

In this case the error is:

> ERROR_PASSWORD_RESTRICTION
>   1325 (0x52D)
>
> Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password
>   does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the
>   domain.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism to get this level of detail back from LDAP especially on Windows 2003.

Comment: Is it possible to get it in Windows 2008 server Active Directory?

Comment: With Windows 2008 R2, you can use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh128228(PROT.10).aspx to enforce password policies on password resets over LDAP. This still won't give you a specific failure reason, though.